# Fallback to another service endpoint if the first is busy according to status code

Tags: node.js, express, microservices, express-gateway

How is possibile to fallback to another API service if the first try fails with status code of 429 or 500?

Consider this situation:
The gateway should first try a microservice host, but if it timeouts or answer a non 2xx status code it should try a next one.

Comment: When you say "another API service" do you mean a completely different type of API service or do you mean another instance of the service that lives on another host?

Comment: for example localhost:8080/get "redirects" to httpbin.org/v1/get if it returns 4xx or 500 it should fallback to example.org/v2/get

Comment: In that case, can't you just write the code that sends a request to the first service and if that fails, write more code to send the request to the second service? You could also in theory just write another abstraction on top of it. There's many different types of integration patterns for this as well. One other question I have though is whether `httpbin.org/v1/get` is the preferred data source over `example.org/v2/get`?

Comment: To the client it should be completely transparent. I don't want to write code for each type of client in web, mobile etc Maybe a priority fîeld of ordered array council be a good order preference. Do you think I can achieve this goal with express gateway?

Comment: I see so you don't already have a service that is in the middle yet. Based on your question, since you didn't mention that your client was a mobile or web front end, it was difficult to tell. If you had a service in the middle to coordinate that workflow you would be fine though correct?

Comment: Probably yes. But by adding another layer do you mean adding another express api gateway?

Comment: API gateway or just another proxy service where the logic lives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported in Express Gateway out of the box. If a request is failing, you'll get a failed request.

Right now you can specify multiple [urls for a serviceEndpoint](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/configuration/gateway.config.yml/serviceEndpoints/#description) that will be used, but in a round robin manner; therefore you'll still get an error first, before trying again with the second service.

Express Gateway could — and maybe should — handle such case. In meantime I'd suggest you to look to other alternatives offered by your infrastructure. Consul could be the way to go.